# Forword incoming email to all existing emails via .qmail

Tags: email, qmail

Is it possible to forward incoming emails to all other email adresses on the server?
Let's say you have "office@example.org" and every employee shall also get the emails sent to this address.
(Not using .qmail but something different is sadly not possible on the server)